# SELECT opposite set of rows of complex query

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, select

This gives me a list of users who have used external funding.

```
SELECT
  table_user.user as user,
  sum(table_deposit.amount) as TotalExternalDeposits,payby,pro_id
FROM table_deposit inner join table_user on table_deposit.user = table_user.user 
WHERE  table_deposit.pro_id <>  'Cash A/C'
AND  table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  '%adj%'
AND table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  'Xmas%'
AND table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  'X-mas%'
group by table_user.user
order by table_user.user
```

My problem is now I need a list of users who have not used external funding (`TotalExternalDeposits = 0`).  I'm lost.

When I try adding something like: `HAVING TotalExternalDeposits = 0` I get an empty set.  I know there are thousands of users that did not use external funding.

Comment: Have you tried to use a WHERE clause instead?

Comment: If you can try using as meaningful a title as you can for your question, it is much appreciated by readers. I've tweaked it for you.

Comment: Sounds to me like he wants to get the opposite set of rows than what the query gives. I have a suggested edit with a title stating such. (Two edits went underneath my initial attempts at it. =/)

Comment: @LarryPenrod . . . I think you need to edit the question.  The first sentence is "This gives me a list of users who have used external funding."  The second query in my answer gets the list of users who have no external funding, based on the definition in the first query (I believe).  I suspect there are other conditions at work.  It would help if you would describe the relationship between "external funding" and the conditions in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `join` is not filtering out any users that you are looking for, you could just use `not`:

```
SELECT table_user.user as user, sum(table_deposit.amount) as TotalExternalDeposits,payby,pro_id
FROM table_deposit inner join
     table_user
    on table_deposit.user = table_user.user 
WHERE not (`table_deposit`.pro_id <>  'Cash A/C' AND 
           `table_deposit`.batch NOT LIKE  '%adj%' AND
           table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  'Xmas%' AND
           table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  'X-mas%'
          )
group by `table_user`.user
order by `table_user`.user
```

However, this gets users that have accounts that are not "external funding".  That is, the above gets users that have at least one non-external funding account.  You may want to be sure that *no* accounts are external funding (rather than *any*).  In that case, you want to move the conditions to a `having` clause, where you can count the rows that match -- and be sure the value is 0:

```
SELECT tu.user as user, sum(td.amount) as TotalExternalDeposits, payby, pro_id
FROM table_user tu left outer join
     table_deposit td
     on td.user = tu.user 
group by tu.user
having sum((td.pro_id <>  'Cash A/C' AND 
            td.batch NOT LIKE  '%adj%' AND
            td.batch NOT LIKE  'Xmas%' AND
            td.batch NOT LIKE  'X-mas%'
           ) or td.user is null
          ) = 0
order by tu.user;
```

I also used table aliases for the tables.  I think that makes it easier to read.

Comment: The first one is definitely not what I want.  I'm not totally following the second one.

Comment: Ahh, the second one wasn't finished yet.  Let me try.

Comment: @LarryPenrod . . . Sorry about that.  There was sort of a stream-of-consciousness thing going on, as I better understood the query.  I'm done for now.

Comment: On the second one.  I get a similar set.  None of the sums are zero.

Comment: Oops, the "= 0" didn't exist yet.  Let me try again.

Comment: That is still only giving me values > 0.

Comment: For example, I have a user that has two deposit records where the pro_id = 'Cash A/C'.  I want to exclude all 'Cash A/C' records.  It's like he isn't showing up because he doesn't have any matching records, only records I don't want.  So in his case because the 'Cash A/C' records are ignored, he should have a zero value.  But instead, he is not included in the record set.

Comment: @LarryPenrod . . . The answer made an explicit assumption about the join, which appears to be wrong.  You want an outer join and need a test in the `having` for no matches.

Comment: @LarryPenrod . . . I edited the second query so it should now work for you.

Comment: The query runs for at least 15 mins on a 6 core dedicated server (disk is so-so) and never finishes and the site is down while it is running.

Answer (score 0):

As the HAVING-clause does not work, it sounds like that those users, who have not used external funding, do not have rows in table_deposit. If this is the case, your query should be something like:

```
SELECT
  table_user.user as user,
  0 as TotalExternalDeposits,
  payby,
  pro_id
FROM table_user 
WHERE user NOT IN (
  SELECT user
  FROM table_deposit
)
```

Comment: I will give this a shot when I get control of the server again.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an either or and you just need the opposite set of your query, just reverse the criteria:

```
SELECT
  table_user.user as user,
  sum(table_deposit.amount) as TotalExternalDeposits,payby,pro_id
FROM table_deposit inner join table_user on table_deposit.user = table_user.user 
WHERE  table_deposit.pro_id =  'Cash A/C'
OR  table_deposit.batch  LIKE  '%adj%'
OR table_deposit.batch  LIKE  'Xmas%'
OR table_deposit.batch  LIKE  'X-mas%'
group by table_user.user
order by table_user.user
```

Comment: All of the users returned have external funding (>0).

Comment: So it's not an 'either or' situatioon, you could set your original query as a subquery and `LEFT JOIN` to it to exclude records it returns.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `HAVING` will do the trick but may be you failed with it because you seem to forget to add `payby` and `pro_id` in the `GROUP BY` clause or may be because you tried with the alias.

```
 SELECT
   table_user.user as user,
   sum(table_deposit.amount) as TotalExternalDeposits,payby,table_deposit.pro_id
 FROM table_deposit inner join table_user on table_deposit.user = table_user.user 
 WHERE  table_deposit.pro_id <>  'Cash A/C'
 AND  table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  '%adj%'
 AND table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  'Xmas%'
 AND table_deposit.batch NOT LIKE  'X-mas%'
 GROUP BY table_user.user,payby,table_deposit.pro_id
 HAVING sum(table_deposit.amount) = 0
 ORDER BY table_user.user
```